# Selenium and Service Workers offline mode

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-devtools

I have tests using network throttling on chrome to turn off internet connection. I'm testing SPA.
Starting from 85 version of Chrome these tests are failed due to turned on connection.
Does anybody know a workaround for this broken function?

Turning off connection using this code:

```
self.driver.set_network_conditions(
                latency=0,
                offline=True,
                download_throughput=500 * 1024,
                upload_throughput=500 * 1024)
```

UPD: I have found out when I unregister service workers with chrome dev tools connection loses.

So, my SPA uses service worker as proxy for requests. That's why set_network_conditions() doesn't turn off connection. But, for all other urls there is no connection.
[I found my issue here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58513156/chromedriver-offline-network-conditions-seems-to-not-block-service-worker-fetche)

Comment: I've just tried your sniplet and worked like a charm, my browser went offline. After setting the `offline` flag to `False` connection returned to normal. Maybe the test of yours is more sophisticated than what I did :)

Comment: You right. I found, that only for tested site connection is not lost. But when I unregister service workers with chrome dev tools connection loses.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe with the usage of proxy?

```
PROXY = "12.345.678.910:8080" -- Fake address
chrome_options = WebDriverWait.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % PROXY)
```

You just have to set a non-existing proxy address

//Edit
You've mentioned that you have to simulate the connection losing in the middle of the test. Still, proxy I think, is the only solution. Steps:

```
1. Init and run local proxy server in your test
2. Run WebDriver with the reference to running proxy server created in step 1.
3. Perform online steps
4. Stop ProxyServer
5. Perform offline steps
```

More about proxy: https://wonderproxy.com/blog/a-step-by-step-guide-to-setting-up-a-proxy-in-selenium/

Comment: It could help to open browser without network connection. But, it my case I need to simulate losing of the network connection on the middle of test case execution. It worked perfect for me earlier.

Comment: Could you check if network conditions are properly set after set_network_conditions() invocation? Http get request http://{remoteWebDriverAddress}/session/{sessionId}/chromium/network_conditions

Comment: Conditions are set correctly. I'm checking this using get_network_conditions() method.

Comment: Ok, so it's clearly a ChromeDriver issue :((( definitely, you should report it https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/list?sort=-id

Comment: I think that proxy is the only solution - I've added my idea how to achieve the connection losing during test execution